# D3.js - Trying to get second set of data points to populate

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a d3 visualization and I have a timer that controls the sequence of events. What I'm trying to do is show a barchart (which simultaneously shows the corresponding data points on a map in the background) and then show ANOTHER bar chart (which will also simultaneously show that bar charts corresponding data points on a map).

I was able to get it to work for the first one, including getting the data points to appear and then disappear on the map, however I can not get it to work for the second set. My theory is i'm not doing something correct with labeling my attributes - ie classes / ids. However perhaps not. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var cities2010 = svg.append("g");

cities2010.selectAll(".city_2010")
        .data(crimes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "city_2010")
        .attr('id', function (d) { return "id_2010_" + d.rank_pop; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0)
        .style("fill", "#DA6761")
        .attr("r", 0)
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection([d.longitude, 
        d.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection([d.longitude, 
        d.latitude])[1]; });
```

.....
This part works

```
    cities2010.selectAll(".city_2010").attr("id", "dot1")
    .filter(function(d) { return d.Characteristics == "Sticky" && 
    "Gooey" && "Tasty";}) 
    .transition().delay(delay*1).ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(2000)
    .attr("r", function(d) {return rScale(d.NumberOfVictims);})
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);


    cities2010.selectAll(".city_2010").attr("id", 
    "dot1").transition().delay(delay*3).duration(1000) 
    .style("opacity",0).remove();
```

Then some more stuff happens, everything else works fine, but then I try to replicate what I did before with the following code and I can't get the dots to populate in the background

```
    cities2010.selectAll(".city_2010").attr("id", "dot2") 
    .filter(function(d) { return d.Characteristics == "Sour" && 
    "Bitter" && "Creamy";}) 
    .transition().delay(delay*4).ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(2000)
    .attr("r", function(d) {return rScale(d.NumberOfVictims);})
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);


    cities2010.selectAll(".city_2010").attr("id", 
    "dot2").transition().delay(delay*6).duration(1000) 
    .style("opacity",0).remove();
```

Comment: what is the use of (and results in illegal HTML) `.attr("id", "dot1")`? Your filter logic is flawed.

Comment: It looks like you remove all circles in the first transition set (`selectAll(...).transition()...remove()`) - this transitions and removes all circles not just the ones that you filtered. As a result, there are no circles left to filter, transition, and remove the second go around. You could drop the remove() from all transitions and see if that helps.

Comment: @AndrewReid thanks for the response. Unfortunately I tried your suggestion and I'm still getting the same results.